# Where does the radius integral go in the partitition function?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

I am confused about a given solution for the following exercise:

A thermodynamic system consists of N atoms in the Volume V. Every atom has a magnetic moment. The hamiltonian can be written as a sum of two parts, where H0 describes the system in the absence of a magnetic field, and H1 describes the influence of the homogenous field B. B is directed towards the z axis. Calculate the canonical partition function.

Here is what I did:[image]

I used spherical coordinates which is why my hamiltonian has the cos term.
Z0 contains everything not involved with the dq integral.

**My question is:
What do I do with that radius integral, since it diverges?**

I would like to show you the solution of the textbook, because they do something I don't understand:

[image]

As you might notice, they mostly did exactly what I did. Still:

- Where does this (4pi)^N term come from? It looks like the solid angle or something like that.
- Where did their radius integral go? Did they put it into their Z0?

Comment: Are your $Z_0$ and the textbook's $Z_N^{(0)}$ exactly the same?

Comment: I am not quite sure. I suspect that they are not the same, and that they just did not evaluate the radius integral by simply pulling it into their Z0.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the $\theta_i$ which are the direction of the atomic spins with the $\theta$'s from when  you unnecessily and confusingly introduced polar coordinates for positions  of the particles. They are completely unrelated.   The partition function for the spin part
$$
Z_{\rm spin} =  \frac 1{4\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^\pi \sin\theta d\theta e^{-\beta\mu B \cos\theta}\\
=\frac {1}{4\pi} 2\pi \int_{-1}^{1} d[\cos\theta] e^{-\beta \mu B \cos\theta}
$$
The $1/{4\pi}$ comes from the area of the unit sphere (which is the  phase space for the spin and  nothing to do with $d^npd^nq$) ) and is there to normalize the probability of the spin direction which is a unit vector ${\bf n}= (\cos\phi \sin\theta, \sin\phi \sin \theta, \cos \theta)$.

As the spin does not affect the motion of the particles, the full partition function for a single atom is simply a product
$$
Z_{\rm tot}= Z_{\rm kinetic} Z_{\rm spin}
$$

If you are copying the solution from your book drectly, it seems that the first line is *incorrect* because it does not include the $B$ field interaction at all, nor the integral over the  spin phase space. That first line is just $Z_{\rm kinetic}$